# how can i work out pickle error in aws lambda python? and __main__ bootstrap etc

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

```
def main(s):
    with open('pipe.dat', 'rb') as fp:
        pipe = pickle.load(fp)
```

this python code makes error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Can't get attribute 'tokenize' on <module '__main__' from '/var/runtime/bootstrap'>",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 702, in _load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 671, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 783, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/hand.py\", line 2, in <module>\n    import SentimentModeling\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/SentimentModeling.py\", line 72, in <module>\n    event = main(s)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/SentimentModeling.py\", line 37, in main\n    pipe = pickle.load(fp)\n"
  ]
}
```

I can't handle these errors.

I made layer about module : sklearn  numpy joblib
use spicy & numpy (served by lambda)
lambda python and modules' version is 3.8

and make pipe.dat is

```
pipe = Pipeline([('vect', tfidf), ('cif', logistic)])
pipe.fit(train_x, train_y)

predict_y = pipe.predict(test_x)
print(accuracy_score(test_y, predict_y)*100)
print(classification_report(test_y, predict_y))

with open('pipe.dat', 'wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(pipe, fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using python 3.8 and pickle with lambda.

I change the runtime to 3.6 and pickle started to work.

I also used .pkl files, not .dat.

```
def load_pickle_tfidf_vocab():
  with open("tfidf_vocab.pkl", "rb") as f:
    raw_data_tfidf = f.read()
  tfidf_vocab = pickle.loads(raw_data_tfidf)
  return tfidf_vocab
```

I was also struggling with packing the dependancies for deployment, so I switched to the cloud9 IDE. I pip installed everything into the folder and then automatically deployed from the IDE itself.